# Using a mocked object form multiple threads

Tags: multithreading, easymock

I've inherited a piece of legacy code and I'm now struggling with a test which fails sometimes.

The test setup goes like this:

```
ADao aDao = EasyMock.createNiceMock(ADao.class);
aDao.aCall(EasyMock.eq(anObject), EasyMock.eq(true));
EasyMock.expectLastCall().andReturn(TestHelper.getAList(anObject));
```

Then the `aDao` is passed to a controller for some worker threads, the controller starts N threads and the test communicates with one of the threads using event queues.

The problem I'm having is that when the worker threads try to use the mocked Dao, they don't get back the list passed to `andReturn` but its copy, and the copy sometimes is incomplete. `TestHelper.getAList` returns an `ArrayList` of 139 items, but the mock sometimes returns a perfect copy, sometimes a copy with 14 or 16 items. I believe the copying is still performed in another thread because iterating over the returned list throws `ConcurrentModificationException`.

Is there a way to make EasyMock either a/ use the object it was set up with instead of a copy or b/ finish copying before the object is passed to a caller?

(Marking EasyMock with `makeThreadSafe(..., false)` does not solve the problem.)

Answer (score 0):

OK, I solved the problem with

```
EasyMock.expectLastCall().andAnswer(new IAnswer<List>() { ... });
```